# How do I add an object to a dictionary in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have a dictionary and want to add a new object to it but compiler give error that it not mutable.

like code below:

```
dict[@"key"] = @"something new";
```

Comment: Already asked and answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519957/add-values-in-nsmutabledictionary-in-ios-with-objective-c

Comment: Show us the exact error message. If the dictionary is defined and init as a `NSDictionary`, why not using `NSMutableDictionary` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add values in NSMutableDictionary in iOS with Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519957/add-values-in-nsmutabledictionary-in-ios-with-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to mutate an immutable object. You need to create a mutable copy and the add the new key-value

```
NSMutableDictionary *mut = [dict mutableCopy];
mut[@"new key"] = @"new value";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the dictionary immutable, you can do:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"something new", @"key", nil];
```